# restartable generator available in Python Standard Library?

Tags: python

I can't imagine that I'm the first to write a class like this:

```
class RestartableGenerator:
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.g().__iter__()

if __name__=='__main__':
    def gen():
        print 'Generating'
        for i in range(5):
            yield i
    i = RestartableGenerator(gen)
    print 'Using'
    print list(i)
    print list(i)
```

The test produces this output:

```
Using
Generating
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Generating
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I didn't find it in the Standard Library. I looked in itertools and functools.

Is it really not there? If it is, where?

Was it considered unnecessary, because when you want to evaluate a sequence multiple times, you better store it in a list?

Edit 1:
My use case is that I want it to be tranparent for the consumer that the sequence is, for memory consumption reasons, a generator instead of a list.

Edit 2: If there's no such class in the Standard Library, what name do you think is appropriate? ParenthesisRemover? MultipleTimesIterable? Anything else? Why?

Comment: I would expect to be able to do `next(i)` and get `1` and `next(i)` and get `2`... And if it doesn't support `next` it's broken as a generator anyway... A generator that has to be materialised to a `list` must as well be a `list` to start with...

Comment: @Jon Clements: The materializing to a list is just because otherwise, print would not print the contents. As with every normal generator.

Comment: Could you explain the difference you're trying to achieve  between this and `itertools.cycle`?

Comment: @Jon Clements: Cycle builds a single infinite sequence by repeating another sequence. But I want a sequence which I can use in multiple, finite, for loops.

Comment: After *any* operation, it resets then.... so, `list(islice(i, 3))` to start gets me `[0, 1, 2]` - now I could reasonably expect the second `list(i)` to give me `[3, 4]`, but I get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`... So, if I wanted to incrementally consume from it - I'd have to materialise the entire lot anyway... So, it doesn't make much sense, breaks all expectations of how it should work, and won't play nicely with all the other toys in `itertools`... So - that's my reasoning for something like this not being included in the stdlib

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify it a little:

```
class RestartableGenerator:
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.g()
```

Calling `gen()` returns a generator object. The generator object has a `next` method, which is the kind of object which `__iter__` must return.

There is no need for `RestartableGenerator`, however, since it does nothing that `gen` itself can not do. Instead of holding `gen` in a class attribute, just hold on to `gen` itself.

```
def gen():
    print 'Generating'
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

print 'Using'
print list(gen())
print list(gen())
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly restartable in the sense of going back to the beginning of the sequence. Each `__iter__` call creates a new generator that will rerun the generator code, potentially reexecuting side effects and producing different results. If you want independent iterators over a generated sequence, that's what `list` or [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) are for. Otherwise, it's clearer to explicitly call the generator function again, so this isn't very useful. You save a pair of parentheses at the cost of less explicit, more bug-prone code.

Note that if you want a lazy sequence type, where iterating over it generates elements on the fly, but you can iterate over it repeatedly, you should define its `__iter__` method as a generator:

```
class Primes(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in itertools.count():
            if is_prime(i):
                yield i
```

This isn't a "restartable generator", but it sounds like what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out itertools.tee. But my use case is that I want it to be tranparent for the consumer that the sequence is, for memory consumption reasons, a generator instead of a list.

Comment: It's not about saving a pair of parentheses. It's because, for another producer, there really is a list. Of course I could, for that other producer, add the parentheses with a lambda expression. I like the RestartableGenerator better, though. Don't want to touch the other producer, or the consumer. Motivation: "A sequence is something you can use in a for loop. Without adding parentheses."

Comment: What's better in your Primes class? Seems like a special case of RestartableGenerator.

Comment: @Sebastian: Conceptual clarity, mostly. It's not a generator and doesn't claim to be one.

Comment: But the Primes class mixes two concerns into one class: removing the parentheses (what RestartableGenerator does) and generating the values (what my example fuction gen does). Maybe I should just choose another name (ParenthesisRemover? MultipleTimesIterable?) to satisfy all the guys who complain about it not beeing a "real" generator?